# T-SQL SELECT query with dates assistance

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Update

I think there's an easier solution that'll save processing time as well. I could just delete all records that that have status = 'completed' and status = 'ongoing' before completed.

That way I only have to simply query to First_value where status = 'ongoing'.

How would I write that?

---

I'm working on a database. I have a table with records that are as follows, quotations describe the columns input, the focus of my question is on Date and Status

- Name "Users name is auto populated from CSV"
- Location "NC,SC,NJ, ETC"
- City "Carthage, Myrtle Beach, ETC"
- Date "Date record was entered is automatically input by SQL when importing CSV in format YEAR-MM-DD"
- Status "Ongoing or Completed are the only two entries"

The `Date` column and `status` columns are updated regularly.

I need my `SELECT DISTINCT` query to return the record by the first date when the Status column = 'Ongoing'. That part, I know how to do. However, whenever a records Status column goes to 'Completed' one day and a new record is added later with the Status as ongoing, I see the first ever record where the Status field = 'Ongoing'.

I attached a visual of what the I'm talking about. I need my query to return the 3rd box from the left and not the first.

[image: visual of what the I'm talking about]

Comment: Perhaps match against `max(Date)`.

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You could use a subquery that returns the minimum date when status was `'Ongoing` and after which no record with status `Completed` exists, like :

```
SELECT t.*
FROM mytable t
WHERE t.status = 'Ongoing'
AND t.date = (
    SELECT MIN(t1.date)
    FROM mytable t1
    WHERE t1.status = 'Ongoing'
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE status = 'Completed' AND date > t1.date)
)
```

Comment: It didn't work, the results I pull are from records that only have had multiple 'Ongoing' statuses. The other part I forgot to mention is that not every initial record will start with 'completed'. 

What if I delete all records from the latest completed status down for that set of records? I process data in batches, so it wouldn't be to difficult to get SQL Agent to run for me.

Comment: @JT : it is hard to understand exactly what you expect... Please update your question with sample data and expected output so we can try and provide a proper answer.

Answer (score 0):

To paraphrase...

- You want one record per `name, location, city` combination?
- That record must itself have `status = 'Ongoing'` but also not have a record immediately before it with `status = 'Ongoing'`.
- Of such potential records, you want the last one.

Using analytical functions you can do that...

```
WITH
    with_previous_status
AS
(
    SELECT
        *,
        LEAD(status, 1, 'Ongoing')
           OVER (PARTITION BY name, location, city
                     ORDER BY date DESC
                )
                   AS previous_status
    FROM
        yourTable
),
    filtered_and_sorted
(
    SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER()
            OVER (PARTITION BY name, location, city
                      ORDER BY date DESC
                 )
                    AS sequence_number
    FROM
        with_previous_status
    WHERE
        previous_status <> 'Ongoing'
        AND      status  = 'Ongoing'
)
SELECT
    name, location, city, date, status
FROM
    filtered_and_sorted
WHERE
    sequence_number = 1
```

Although it is longer code than using a `NOT EXISTS()` correlated subquery, this should minimise the cost to execute and so is potentially faster.

For maximum performance, you may want to have a single index on...

```
CREATE INDEX
    mytable_nlcds
ON mytable (
    name,
    location,
    city,
    date DESC,
    status
)
```

Answer (score 0):

So,

I've basically created two tables. One with all ongoing and another with all completed.

Then I just append new records to my completed table, then run a CREATE TO based on SELECT * Last_value([t1.Date]). Then I run a DELETE left join on the ongoing table ON complete table by name and city, where t1.date > t2.date.

This solved the issue for me. It's an extra step, but it runs quickly and will keep my DB size low.

Thank you everyone for your suggestions!